# Как сделать границы Floating searchview прозрачными?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здравствуйте, в fsv не могу понять, как сделать границы виджета прозрачными или же поменять их цвет. В xml не нашёл нужного аттрибута, может быть это можно сделать программно? Для наглядности, скриншот приложения, где видно границы виджета на фоне.

Comment: android:elevation="0dp" не помогает ?

Comment: Вы бы хоть указали, какую именно библиотеку используете. В андроид сдк нет такого виджета.